# Calculus by FTC

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a continuous real valued function defined on a closed interval $[a,b]$. Let $F$ be the function defined, for all $x$ in $[a.b]$ by $$F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt$$.

Does it necessary follow that $F(x)$ is of class $C^\infty$ on the open set $(a,b)$? Or is it simply $C^1$?

Comment: If $f$ isn't differentiable then can $F$ be $C^\infty$?

Comment: @anon, no (10 char)

Comment: Actually, $f$ is $C^k$ if and only if $F$ is $C^{k+1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on @anon's comment, if you suppose $f$ is a continuous non-differentiable function, say $f(x)=|x|$ on the interval $[-1,1]$, then your $F(x)$ is continuously differentiable, that is, $C^1[-1,1]$, but it is not $C^2[-1,1]$ since $f$ is not differentiable.

You can in fact, take a continuous, nowhere differentiable function $f$ and get that $F$ is $C^1$ but not $C^2$ at any point.

Comment: that's what I was thinking, the absolute value. You are speaking about a nowhere differentiable function for $f(t)$ right?

Comment: Right (for the second part).

Comment: If $f$ is $C^{n-1}$, does it follow that $F$ is $C^{n}$?

Comment: If $F'=f$ and $f\in C^{n-1}$, what does that say about $F^{(n)}=(F')^{(n-1)}$?

Comment: I am tempted to multiply $(n - 1)^2$

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be tempting, but notice that we have $F^{(n)}=(F')^{(n-1)}=f^{(n-1)}$, which exists since $f\in C^{n-1}$.

Comment: I thought that because $f \in C^(n-1)$, then I would get $(C^{n -1})^{n - 1}$

Comment: I see; no, the exponent represents the number of derivatives.